# Bounded operator on a product of several spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am studying some issues relative to operators, especially bounded operators, but my professor asked me the following  and I couldn’t answer him:
Let
$$B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a &b \\[4 pt]
 b & a\end{array}\right],$$
be a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, and $x\in \mathbb{C}$. We define
$$
C \left[\begin{array}{c}x \\[4 pt]
 x\end{array}\right] = \left(0,0,0,B \left[\begin{array}{c}x \\[4 pt]
 x\end{array}\right]^T \right)\in \mathbb{C}\times H^1((a,b)\cup(c,d))\times L^2((a,b)\cup(c,d)) \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}.
$$

**Is $C$ a bounded linear operator? why ?.**

Comment: Hint: Is the map $x\mapsto (0,x)$ bounded? Is $(x,x)\mapsto(0,x,x)$ bounded?

Comment: @Chrystomath How can I prove that $x\to (0,x)$ is bounded ? I read the definition but I can not conclude that.

Comment: Show the map is linear, and that $\|(0,x)\|=\|x\|$ (or at least $\|(0,x)\|\le c\|x\|$). You need to be clear about the definition of a norm on a product space first.